# Auto update even when it is disabled

Tags: apt, updates, 17.10

Although I had disabled the auto update of ubuntu 17.10. However, I see a window which says when do you want to reboot to install the updates!!

Is that normal?

[image]

Comment: Are the updates possibly coming from `unattended-upgrades`? Does `systemctl status unattended-upgrades` show anything?

Comment: The service is said to be active!

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades` or disable from `systemctl` should do it.

Comment: OK. I disable it. Waiting to see what will happen in the future. Thanks.

Comment: yw! Let me know if that works.

Comment: One, you should regularly update your system and software, and for that you should also leave the `artful-security` and `artful-updates`, optionally also `artful-backports` repositories enabled. Two, you can disable the automatic check for new available updates, which you already seem to have done, but then you should regularly update manually. Three, the reboot prompt is caused by installing e.g. a kernel update or update of another vital component that can't be replaced on the fly. Have you ran any manual update since the last reboot?

Comment: Btw. you could silence these reboot prompts for the session by deleting the `/run/reboot-required*` files...

Comment: @ByteCommander: The concern about short term update is the system mess. I had many problems before about this issue. For example, some packages are updated and without noticing that when you want to update another package, you will get unmet dependencies. About kernel upgrades, I do have a concern about a broken nvidia driver. These are based on my past experiences. Maybe they are not generally true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable unattended upgrades:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades
```

Select "no" when asked "Configuring unattended-upgrades" then select "ok".

More information on unattended-upgrades can be found at:

[wiki.debian.org](https://wiki.debian.org/UnattendedUpgrades)

[help.ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticSecurityUpdates)